# AWS amplify graphql appsync - how to replace array instead of append?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify with graphql and appsync.
I have a field called myArray that is an array of strings.
I would like to replace the value of myArray with a new array.

When I try to do this, graphql adds my input to the existing array, instead of replacing the array with my input.

How can I replace my array with a new array, instead of appending to the existing array.
Here is my code and the result:

// My query:

````
    updateFrame(input: {id: "94cf1635-a336-4619-99eb-53c081f57bea", myArray: ["new value"]}) {
      id
      testOrder
    }
  }```
  

// Mutated data
```{
  "data": {
    "updateFrame": {
      "id": "94cf1635-a336-4619-99eb-53c081f57bea",
      "myArray": [
        "oldValue",
        "oldValue",
        "new value"
      ]
    }
  }```[
}
````

Comment: I have the opposite problem - I need to append add an input to an existing array but it will just replace the whole array with the new input

Comment: i have the issue mentioned by OP, wondering if you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this as well. Note, my confidence that this is a correct answer is not 100%:

- If you have DataStore enabled, the backend's logic for conflict resolution may be attempting to merge the data, rather than replace it.
- By including a value for "_version", data will be overwritten as you wish.
- You have to make sure you are using the current/latest value for "_version". If you are lower or higher, it will either fail or save/return the original value.
- IMO, the documentation about mixing DataStore with GraphQL is somewhat opaque in parts. So I have a nagging worry that doing this (mixing DataStore with GraphQL queries) is unsupported. I.e., that just because it works it isn't always going to work.

Comment: The key here is you need to update the CURRENT version for it to recognize that it's an UPDATE rather than an APPEND.